# Conditional rendering element from a list as a modal in React

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

I am very new to programming and working on an MVP project for a FS app where I have a small database of books which I render through a .map. Currently, I am rendering the cover of all the books in my database and when I click on the cover it shows the title, author and summary. The functionality is working but it is looking rubbish as when I click any book it pushes everything around and I would like for it to show as a modal box above my list of books. This is my code below, do you have any idea how to achieve that? Thanks so much :)

````
import Filter from "./components/filter"
import './App.css';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      books:[],
      showBook: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getBookclub();
  }

  getBookclub = () => {
    fetch(`/books`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ books: response });
      });
  };

  handleClick(e){
    for (let i = 0 ; i < this.state.books.length ; i++) {
      this.state.showBook[i] = false;
    }
    let bookShow = [...this.state.showBook];
    bookShow[e.target.name-1] = true;
    this.setState({
      showBook: bookShow
    });           
  }

  renderLibrary() {
  return this.state.books.map((books,id) => {
    return(
      <li key={id} className="book-list">
        <span onClick ={() => this.getBookclub(books.id)}>
          <div>
          **<img onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)} name={books.id} src={books.cover} alt={books.title}/>              
          </div>
          <div className={this.state.showBook[books.id-1] ? "bookDetails" : "bookhidden"}>
            <br/>
            <div className="cover-book-show">
            <h5>{books.title}</h5>
            </div>
            <div className="author-book-show">
            <h6>{books.author}</h6>
            </div>
            <div className="summary-book-show">
            <p>{books.summary}</p>
            </div>**
          </div>
        </span>
      </li>
    )
  })}
  

  filterBook(filteredList){
    this.setState({
      books: filteredList
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Books</h1>
        <div>
          <Filter filterBook={filteredList => this.filterBook(filteredList)}/>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <ul>
          **<div className="all-books">
            {this.renderLibrary()}
          </div>**
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}```
````